# ORA-00936: missing expression whilst executing query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Ruby to communicate with the database and I have a statistics page which shows stats for devices. Unfortunately I am getting the following error when a select query is executed to show the page:

> ERROR -- : StatementInvalid: Java::JavaSql::SQLSyntaxErrorException:
> ORA-00936: missing expression

```
SELECT
   COUNT(*) AS count_all,
   date(request_time) AS date_request_time,
   "REQUESTS"."DEVICE_ID" AS requests_device_id 
FROM
   "REQUESTS" 
WHERE
   (
      customer_id = 1 
      AND request_method != 'OPTIONS' 
      AND request_time BETWEEN '2021-10-27 00:00:00' AND '2021-11-03 23:59:59.000999'
   )
   AND 
   (
      device_id IS NOT NULL 
      AND request_time BETWEEN '2021-10-27 00:00:00' AND '2021-11-03 23:59:59.000999'
   )
GROUP BY
   date(request_time),
   "REQUESTS"."DEVICE_ID"
```

What expression is missing? I seemed to have miss something.

Comment: Did u try this query in the db directly?

Comment: may be ; after GROUP BY
   date(request_time),
   "REQUESTS"."DEVICE_ID"

Comment: `date(arg)` - there's no such function in Oracle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The query has two issues:

- Replace `date()` with `trunc()`.
- To use timestamp literals use `to_date()` (or `timestamp 'literal'`).

For example, your query could run as:

```
SELECT
   COUNT(*) AS count_all,
   trunc(request_time) AS date_request_time,
   "REQUESTS"."DEVICE_ID" AS requests_device_id 
FROM
   "REQUESTS" 
WHERE
   (
      customer_id = 1 
      AND request_method != 'OPTIONS' 
      AND request_time BETWEEN to_date('2021-10-27 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
                           AND to_date('2021-11-03 23:59:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
   )
   AND 
   (
      device_id IS NOT NULL 
      AND request_time BETWEEN to_date('2021-10-27 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
                           AND to_date('2021-11-03 23:59:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
   )
GROUP BY
   trunc(request_time),
   "REQUESTS"."DEVICE_ID"
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5938656076e02cad592a6bf17d971a68).